# TypeError: 'QLabel' object is not callable

Tags: pyqt4

When I run the demo program as below, the mainwindow will call the childwindow, then the childwindow will call a widget. I want to get some attribute of this widget such as "messageLabel",but it will report an error that TypeError: 'QLabel' object is not callable. Then how to modify this error? Thank you,

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow Window!")
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 100, 100) 
        self.centerWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centerWidget)

        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("&Button")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.centerWidget.setLayout(layout)    

class ChildWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChildWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        #QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Child Window!")
        self.centerWidget = Widget(parent)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centerWidget)

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.messageLabel = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.messageLabel.setText("How to get this message label?")
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.messageLabel)         
        self.setLayout(layout) 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = MainWindow()  

def showChildWindow():
    child_win = ChildWindow(myapp)
    child_win.show()
    childLabel = child_win.centerWidget.messageLabel().text().__str__().__str__()    #how to call the messageLabel?
    print childLabel

myapp.show()
QtCore.QObject.connect(myapp.pushButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),showChildWindow)  
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There may be other problems but this line is throwing the current exception: `childLabel = child_win.centerWidget.messageLabel().text().__str__().__str__()`

Comment: It should instead be: `childLabel = child_win.centerWidget.messageLabel.text()`